# maintaining their positions

Tags: meaning-in-context

Russian forces continued to prepare for an assault on Severodonetsk and intensified operations around Lyman. Russian forces continued to prioritize holding ***positions*** around the Russian border to prevent further Ukrainian advances north of Kharkiv City and will likely continue to do so at the expense of deploying additional reinforcements to other axes of advance. Russian troops focused on maintaining their ***positions*** on the Southern Axis and on conducting rocket, missile, and artillery strikes along the frontline.

Source: https://www.understandingwar.org/backgrounder/russian-offensive-campaign-assessment-may-18

---

I'm not sure if sense 10 matches the use of "***positions***".

> **position** *noun*
>
> **10** [countable, usually plural] a place where a group of people involved in fighting have put men and guns
>
> - They attacked the enemy positions at dawn.
> - The defence stuck firmly to its position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the passage you quote is from an article about warfare, it seems certain that the word **position** is used in the military sense of your Definition 10.